# add button action to input type search

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a widget with a search bar. I want to add a button with the search action on click. This is my HTML and what I have tried with no success:
— when I click on the `search-bar-button` button I get an `Undefined` message —

`php`

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="searchform" action="http://website.test/">
  <label for="terrain-search-form-1">
    <span class="screen-reader-text">Search:</span>
    <input type="search" id="terrain-search-form-1" class="field" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search" name="s">
  </label>
  <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="es">
</form>
<a id="search-bar-button" javascript="void(0)"></a>
```

`js`

```
document.getElementById("search-bar-button").addEventListener("click", function(){
       document.getElementById("terrain-search-form-1").value = this.value;
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What exactly should the button do? Are you trying to set the value of the search bar to what the button's text is? Or, are you trying to submit the search form with the click of the button?

Comment: If this would be a about submitting a form, the form would have a submit button because that is what those buttons are for. I'd assume the anchor is for something different, like scrolling the page or opening a search form widget or something.

Comment: yes, the button should submit the form and open the page the results, as the button works with the Return key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the text of the button to set as the search value, use:

```
document.getElementById("terrain-search-form-1").value = this.innerText
```

If you want the value of an attribute from the button as the search value, use:

```
document.getElementById("terrain-search-form-1").value = this.getAttribute("id");
//this will set the search value to 'search-bar-button'
```

Eventually, to submit the form with the value, use:

```
document.querySelector(".searchform").submit();
```

Comment: `document.querySelector(".searchform").submit();` this is what I was I looking for, thank you :)